# Click Every Word that ends with ".log.gz" in Any Language Compatible with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, osx-yosemite, applescript, string

I have looked up the answer to this already and cannot do this with the programming languages I know, so I'd like the code for this and an explanation as to how it works so I can use this in future instances.

I have to download 300+ .log.gz files from a single page and would prefer not to manually click every single one. They all share the ending of .log.gz and begin with either "2014" or "2015". Is there a fairly simple code that I could execute inside Google Chrome that would allow me to click every single one of these (with a minor delay between each click) without having any manual support? I run Mac OS X Yosemite, if that helps.

EDIT:

The areas, in HTML, appear like this:

```
<tr class="downloadable">
    <td><img src="Images/File.png" alt="File"></td>
    <td>2014-09-24-1.log.gz</td>
    <td>32.67 KB</td>
    <td>September 25, 2014 at 5:00:08 AM GMT+1</td>
</tr>
```

Where I want to click:

```
<td>2014-09-24-1.log.gz</td>
```

Comment: Don't you want to use a download manager as `iGetter`?

Comment: This won't work for me, as the string that I am clicking isn't a separate, downloadable webpage.

Comment: As there is not an `<a href` tag on the page, manually click  works?

Comment: Yes: the javascript in the page listens to those specific areas and, rather than redirecting, sends the file without changing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BigDave's right on the money. Look for an extension that allows you to click-drag an area and open all the links inside, Like [LinkClump](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj?hl=en). I have found that some of these programs can really cause the browser to lag, but that's expected when trying to open up so many links all at once.

Sounds like you're a micro-tasker/mechanical-turk worker?

Another idea is a macro-mouse program, if you can successfully assume that all the links are in a position that can be automatically clicked.

Yet another idea is to get ahold of a "visual programming language", ie, the bot programs that are typically used to cheat on video games, and clue the program to click on links based on their appearance.

Comment: Once again, they are NOT links. They do not redirect to a different site with <a href. The mouse program might work, however, I don't know of any off the top of my head, do you have any suggestions for such?

Comment: Yes, this worked. I used "Auto Mouse Click" by Murgaa, for future reference.

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE Sorry, you kept describing the functionality as that of a link, which is why we've been confused "...manually click every single one.... click every single one... Where I want to click..."

Comment: It was difficult for me to explain. It _does_ require clicking, as it's a javascript onClick event, but it doesn't act like a link.

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE last I remember LinkClump triggers the onClick event and should work fine for you

Answer (score 1):

There's Chrome extensions for doing things like this. After a quick Google search, this turned up:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-master/mcceagdollnkjlogmdckgjakjapmkdjf?hl=en-US

Only has 3/5 stars but it might be what your looking for. I can't vouch for it's usefulness/safety of the download. Search in the extensions store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions to find more options.

Also, in the future if you have code-specific questions, those should be posted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me - the "links", if you will, aren't actually links. They tell the server to send me the files, they are not separate pages. Therefore, I need to click on the words, not download the links.

Comment: If the files are just a list of text ("words") how are they clickable? They would have to be links if they lead to a file download...please explain.

Comment: In the JavaScript for the page, there is an EventListener that detects the clicks specified in the table divided areas. I'm not sure how, as, again, I am completely useless when it comes to JavaScript, but the download is initiated by the JavaScript, not a link.